# Como exibir uma pagina html em um JTextPane?

Tags: java

Pessoal estou tentando exibir/integrar uma pagina php em um `JtextPane`, funciona mas eu não tenho controle do HTML, ele apenas exibe o texto que a página gera e eu gostaria de exibir com o HTML, `<div>`, CSS, mas não estou conseguindo, alguma sugestão ?

Segue o código:

```
JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane();
JTextPane txtpnDescricaomsg = new JTextPane(); 
txtpnDescricaomsg.setText(descricao);
txtpnDescricaomsg.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
js.setViewportView(txtpnDescricaomsg);
js.setBounds(16, 401, 801,220);
getContentPane().add(js);
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez falte setar o tipo de conteúdo do JTextPane assim:

```
JTextPane painel = new JTextPane();
painel.setContentType("text/html");
```

Referencia da resposta completa : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122611/setcontenttypetext-html-for-jtextpane-doesnt-work-as-it-is-expected)